# complex holomorphic function which only has finite roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose that D is a bounded region, *f* $\in$ H(D)$\bigcap$C($\bar D$).Prove that f has only finite roots if f$\neq$0 on $\partial D$.

Comment: A hint: since $f \neq 0$ in $\partial D$, if the set of zeros of $f$ is infinite, it must have an accumulation point inside the disk. What can you say about a holomorphic function whose zeros accumulate to a point?

Comment: Identity theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f$ would have an infinite number of distinct roots. Let $(z_i)$ be a sequence of distinct roots. Since $\bar D$ is compact there exists a sub sequence of $(z_i)$ with a limit $\zeta$. Since $f$ is continuous on $\bar D$, we have $f(\zeta)=0$. Hence lies in the interiour of $D$. A holomorphic function on a region with an accumulation point of zeros inside that region is constant. Hence $f=0$. End of proof.